# Batchnormalization over which dimension?

Tags: pytorch, batch-normalization

Over which dimension do we calculate the mean and std? Is it over the hidden dimensions of the NN Layer, or over all the samples in the batch for every hidden dimension separately?

In the paper it says we normalize over the batch.

In `torch.nn.BatchNorm1d` however the input argument is `num_features`, which makes no sense to me.

Why does pytorch not follow the original paper on Batchnormalization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> over which dimension do we calculate the mean and std?

Over `0`th dimension, for `1D` input of shape `(batch, num_features)` it would be:

```
batch = 64
features = 12
data = torch.randn(batch, features)

mean = torch.mean(data, dim=0)
var = torch.var(data, dim=0)
```

> In torch.nn.BatchNorm1d hower the input argument is "num_features",
> which makes no sense to me.

It is not related to normalization but **reparametrization of `mean` and `var` via `gamma` and `beta` learnable parameters**. From the paper:

[image: batchnorm]

Both parameters used in scale and shift phase are of shape `num_features`, hence we have to pass this value in order to initialize them with specific shape.

Below is an example from scratch implementation for reference:

```
class BatchNorm1d(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features, momentum: float = 0.9, eps: float = 1e-7):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_features = num_features

        self.gamma = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1, self.num_features))
        self.beta = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, self.num_features))
        
        self.register_buffer("running_mean", torch.ones(1, self.num_features))
        self.register_buffer("running_var", torch.ones(1, self.num_features))

        self.momentum = momentum
        self.eps = eps

    def forward(self, X):
        if not self.training:
            X_hat = X - self.running_mean / torch.sqrt(self.running_var + self.eps)
        else:
            mean = X.mean(dim=0).unsqueeze(dim=0)
            var = ((X - mean) ** 2).mean(dim=0).unsqueeze(dim=0)

            # Update running mean and variance
            self.running_mean *= self.momentum
            self.running_mean += (1 - self.momentum) * mean

            self.running_var *= self.momentum
            self.running_var += (1 - self.momentum) * var

            X_hat = X - mean / torch.sqrt(var + self.eps)

        return X_hat * self.gamma + self.beta
```

> Why does pytorch not follow the original paper on Batchnormalization?

It does as one can see